# Change table data set based on Google Maps API results

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a filter which allows me to filter users based on the distance between a location and their address. Data is provided to the table using useMemo, basically like this:

```
const data = useMemo(
  () =>
    contacts.filter(contact => {
      var shouldReturn = true;

      clientFilter.map((filter, i) => {
        if (filter.condition === 'max_10km') {
          const originAddress = `${contact['street']} ${contact['number']}, ${contact['zip']} ${contact['city']}, ${contact['country']}`;
          calculateDistance(originAddress, filter.value, function(distance) {
            console.log('distance is calculated: ', distance);
            if (distance > 10000) {
              console.log('distance is > for', contact['name']);
              shouldReturn = false;
            }
          });
        }
      });
      return shouldReturn;
    }),
  [clientFilter]
);
```

This works fine, in console the results return as I expect them to be. However, my table doesn't update. I suspect it is because the result of the API calls are async, and thus the table is re-rendered before the results are in.

I have tried updating the data using useEffect, but this brings me in a loop which constant re-renders, and thus exceeding the maximum (`Maximum update depth exceeded.`).

How should I go about this? Should I try async functions? If so, how can I wait to update my data until all promises are resolved?

**EDIT 14 NOV**
So, I have been looking further into this today. I have managed to switch the filtering to `useEffect()` instead of `useMemo()`, so currently, it looks like this:

```
const [filteredContacts, setFilteredContacts] = useState(contacts);
const data = useMemo(() => filteredContacts, [filteredContacts]);
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('Log: In useEffect()');
  if (!isLoading) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    (async () => {
      console.log('Log: State has changed, filtering will start');
      filterContacts().then(() => setIsLoading(false));
    })();
  }
}, [clientFilter]);

async function filterContacts() {
  setFilteredContacts(
    contacts.filter(contact => {
      var shouldReturn = true;

      clientFilter.map((filter, i) => {
        if (
          filter.condition === 'equal' &&
          contact[filter.field] != filter.value &&
          shouldReturn
        ) {
          shouldReturn = false;
        }

        if (filter.condition === 'max_10km' && shouldReturn) {
          const originAddress = `${contact['street']} ${contact['number']}, ${contact['zip']} ${contact['city']}, ${contact['country']}`;
          calculateDistance(originAddress, filter.value, async function(
            distance
          ) {
            console.log('Log: Distance is calculated: ', distance);
            if (distance > 10000) {
              console.log(
                'Log: Distance is further away for',
                contact['title']
              );
              shouldReturn = false;
            }
          });
        }
      });
      console.log('Log: About to return shouldReturn value');
      return shouldReturn;
    })
  );
}
```

Now, this works for my other filters, but the async distance calculation still runs after the return of `shouldReturn` has been done. So my logs look like this (I have 16 contacts/users currently):

- Log: In useEffect()
- Log: State has changed, filtering will start
- (16) Log: About to return shouldReturn value
- Log: Distance is calculated: 1324
- Log: Distance is calculated: 4326
- ...

So basically, it still ignores the async state of my function `calculateDistance`. Any ideas?

**EDIT 15/11**
Might be useful as well, this is my `calculateDistance()` function:

```
function calculateDistance(origin, destination, callback) {
  const google = window.google;
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  directionsService.route(
    {
      origin: origin,
      destination: destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    },
    (result, status) => {
      if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        callback(result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
      } else {
        console.error('Google Maps API error: ', status);
        callback(null);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

**EDIT 18/11**
After @Secret's suggestion, I changed the code to:

```
  const shouldRemoveContact = await(filters, contact) = () => {
    for (const filter of filters) {
      if (
        filter.condition === 'equal' &&
        contact[filter.field] != filter.value
      ) {
        return true
      }

     if (filter.condition === 'max_10km') {
        const originAddress = `${contact['street']} ${contact['number']}, ${contact['zip']} ${contact['city']}, ${contact['country']}`

        // please update calculateDistance to return a promise
        const distance = await calculateDistance(originAddress, filter.value)

        return distance > 10000

      }

    return false
    }
  }
   


  async function filterContacts (filters, contact) {
    // for every contact, run them to shouldRemoveContact
    // since shouldRemoveContact is async, we use Promise.all
    // to wait for the array of removeables to be ready
    const shouldRemove = await Promise.all(
      contact.map(c => shouldRemoveContact(filters, c))
    )

    // use shouldRemove to check if contact should be removed
    // and voila!
    return contacts.filter((c, i) => !shouldRemove[i])
  }
```

This results in:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'.
```

on the line:

```
const shouldRemoveContact = await(filters, contact) = () => {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct in your mistake - your `calculateDistance` is async and therefore you can't filter your data properly. Essentially, your code can be boiled down to:

```js
  setFilteredContacts(
    contacts.filter(contact => {
      var shouldReturn = true;

      // THIS IS WHERE CALCULATE IS
      // but it doesn't do anything because it is async
      // so effectively, it does nothing like a comment

      console.log('Log: About to return shouldReturn value');
      return shouldReturn;
    })
  );
```

As you can see, your contacts will never be filtered out as `shouldReturn` will always return `true` - it never changes in the middle of that function!

What you can do is `calculate` the list of filterables beforehand, and then use that to run your filter. Something like this (psuedocode):

```
// given a contact and a list of filters
// asynchronously return if it should or should not be filtered
const shouldRemoveContact = async () => {}

// THEN, in the filterContacts part:

// let's generate an array of calls to shouldRemoveContact
// i.e. [true, true, false, true], where `true` means it should be removed:
// note that we use await Promise.all here, waiting for all the data to be finished.
const shouldRemove = await Promise.all(
  contact.map(c => shouldRemoveContact(filters, c))
)


// we then simply shouldRemove to filter it all out
return contacts.filter((c, i) => !shouldRemove[i])
```

All together:

```
   // given a list of filters and one contact
   // asynchronously returns true or false depending on wheter or not
   // the contact should be removed
   const shouldRemoveContact = async (filters, contact) => {
     for (const filter of filters) {
       if (
         filter.condition === 'equal' &&
         contact[filter.field] != filter.value
       ) {
         return true
       }

      if (filter.condition === 'max_10km') {
         const originAddress = `${contact['street']} ${contact['number']}, ${contact['zip']} ${contact['city']}, ${contact['country']}`

         // please update calculateDistance to return a promise
         const distance = await calculateDistance(originAddress, filter.value)

         return distance > 10000

, async function(
           distance
         ) {
           console.log('Log: Distance is calculated: ', distance);
           if (distance > 10000) {
             console.log(
               'Log: Distance is further away for',
               contact['title']
             );
             shouldReturn = false;
           }
         });
       }
     }

     return false
   }


   async function filterContacts (filters, contact) {
     // for every contact, run them to shouldRemoveContact
     // since shouldRemoveContact is async, we use Promise.all
     // to wait for the array of removeables to be ready
     const shouldRemove = await Promise.all(
       contact.map(c => shouldRemoveContact(filters, c))
     )

     // use shouldRemove to check if contact should be removed
     // and voila!
     return contacts.filter((c, i) => !shouldRemove[i])
   }
```

Comment: Hi @Secret, thx! I get the gist of that, so it helps me a lot. However, I seem to have a couple of syntax errors. First one appears at the `=>` in  `const shouldRemoveContact = await (filters, contact) => {`, and I don't know enough about async functions to fix it. Thought it should be `const shouldRemoveContact = await (filters, contact) = () => {` but that brings me to other errors, so I'm not sure on how to go on. I have updated the original question with my current code, which doesn't give me syntax errors, but the following: `Syntax error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'.` on first line.

Comment: Hmm, I've read your comment a couple times over again, I'll have to give it some proper thought instead of trying to fix it quickly. I'll dive in this weekend.

Comment: @PennyWise Definitely try to spend some time understanding it - the fix is a bit 'tricky' but once you understand it it'll make a lot of sense! Btw, I made a mistake! It should be `async () => {}` instead (I updated my answer)

Comment: I also wrote pseudocode on what the idea behind the solution is

Comment: I have accepted your answer. However, it seems like the actual result (the distance, from calculateDistance function), still results after all promises have been resolved. But I feel like you have given me a lot of information, so I will try to find the solution in the next couple of days. So thank you for the help.

Comment: @PennyWise That is indeed how this solution would work, and how it was originally in the question. Once the clientFilters changed, all the filters would be 'run' and `calculateDistance` would be called for each one if need be, and the results would be filtered once all `calculateDistance` has been done. Do you want the filters/removal to be done dynamically as the `calculateDistance` is done and not all at once?

Comment: I mean, when the filter has ran, so when the results have updated, after that, the distances are calculated and logged to my console. So I have a log for when everything is done (when loading is set to false), and this runs before the calculations have been made. So I think the promises are finished before the results are in.